# how to stop crawl for specific pages in jomres?

Tags: seo, web-crawler, jomres

How to stop stop google crawl for this page https://www.example.com/index.php/en/component/jomres/?Itemid=0&task=search&page=1&towns%5B0%5D=calangute in jomres, is it possible to do in robot.txt file or any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can through robots.txt for this page by adding the below line

```
Disallow : /index.php/en/component/jomres/?Itemid=0&task=search&page=1&towns%5B0%5D=calangute
```

The above line will block only this page, if you want to block all the pages with the above parameters, use the this one

```
Disallow : /index.php/en/component/jomres/?Itemid=*&task=*&page=*&towns%5B0%5D=*
```

Here we changed the dynamic values to stars *, you can customize it as you want and for any specific case.

Comment: Okay thnak you very much... will try with it